# Prepare Custom app on make formerly integromat

Tags: zapier, make.com

I have a custom app on zapier and now I wanted to create a custom app on make (formerly integromat). Can I use the same APIs on both?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can @Sahildeep.  Once the API you are using is a public facing API, it can be used to create a custom app in Make (formerly Integromat).  For more detailed information you can check out the documentation [here](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/)